# Visual studio code python debugger breakpoint won't trigger

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I can't figure out why vscode debugger is not working. I tried everything, but the breakpoints are still not working. Has anyone had a similar problem, and solved it?

My lauch.json file just for reference:

```
{
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"stopOnEntry": true,
Set this to false